# Android ListView notifyDataSetChanged not working properly

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

Hi I am creating a chat application I am uploading, downloading images, videos etc. Everything working fine. I want the user to notify that the percentage of downloading/uploading. Now my issue is when I call notifyDataSetChanged list reach the last position of the list. I find out this is because of my all the list items are reloading. How can I handle this?

My refill adapter code is below...

```
public synchronized void refill(ArrayList<ChatMessagesNew> chatmsg) {
        this.chatMessages.clear();
        this.chatMessages.addAll(chatmsg);
        int count = chatmsg.size();
        if (numberOfMessage < count) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            numberOfMessage = count;
        }else{
        }

    }
```

In the above code numberOfMessage  and count is based on a total number of messages.

How can I handle this?

**Edit 1:**

I am calling refill method like this...

```
 private void refreshListView(){
        ArrayList<ChatMessagesNew> chatmsg = new ArrayList<ChatMessagesNew>();
        chatmsg = getChatMessage(chatmsg);
        if (lvMessages.getAdapter() == null) {

            chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(ChatActivity.this, jid, lvMessages,chatmsg);
            lvMessages.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

        } else {
            ((ChatAdapter) lvMessages.getAdapter()).refill(chatmsg);
        }
    }
```

Note:  If you need any more details please leave your comments.

** I am using BaseAdapter....

Comment: Consider using a RecyclerView, it will allow you to update specific items with the notifyItemChanged(int position) method instead of updating the whole list

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion. If I go for recyclerView I must face 2 issues 1. I need to change each line of code. 2. I don't get the position Maybe 1st item loading of some other items are loading. How can I manage?

Comment: The first thing shouldnt really be a problem, and it is worth the effort. 
The second thing might be solved by updating the visible items in the RecyclerView or maybe keep track of which items have to be updated.

Comment: Could you share some sample code with dealing  this issue?

Comment: Just try something out or create a new question

Comment: @Jeffalee I have change to recycler view same issue occur. Now the list moving to the top position

Comment: @Jeffalee I fixed the issue using recycler view. Thanks for your suggestion